# Formal meaning of 'weight-tying' expression in literature

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoder, word-embedding

I recently came across the term *Weight-tying* regarding auto-encoders and words-embeddings as well - yet couldn't find a clear definition.

My guess is that it means concatenating multiple outputs of ,say, FC layers and feeding to a single layer, thus 'tying' the weights to be influenced by the same 'trigger'.